# Why is this SQL query not working? CS50 Pset7 - movies

Tags: sql, sqlite, cs50

I'm currently working through this https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/7/movies/  and trying to complete 9.sql.

There a database called "movies", with tables: movies (columns: id, title, year), people (id, name, birth) and stars (movie_id, person_id).

The task is:

> write a SQL query to list the names of all people who starred in a
>   movie released in 2004, ordered by birth year. It should return 18,013
>   names.

So far, this is what I've done:

```
SELECT count(distinct name) 
from people
join stars on stars.person_id = people.id
join movies on stars.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE year = 2004;
```

However, this only returns a count of 17,965...

Can anyone see why this might be?

Comment: How can we verify the results? Perhaps the count can reflect that some actors did several movies that year?

Comment: Ivy league college using sqlite and referencing w3schools... I shake my head.

Comment: The database can be downloaded from here: cdn.cs50.net/2019/fall/psets/7/movies/movies.zip

I tried without the "distinct" as well but this then gave too many names...

Comment: I've verified your numbers. Interesting problem.

Comment: If you `count(distinct person_id)`, then you will get 18013. It's reasonable that `name` is not unique. What is unreasonable is the directive in the exam saying you should list only `name`.

Comment: "*to list the names of all people*" should result in `select people.name from ...` rather than `count()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you `count(distinct person_id)`, then you will get 18013. It's reasonable that name is not unique. What is unreasonable is the directive in the exam saying you should list only name.

One way to correctly distinct the names is to execute this:

```
SELECT p.name
from people p
where p.id in (
select distinct s.person_id
from stars s join movies m on s.movie_id = m.id
WHERE m.year = 2004)
```

And if you do it that way, then you don't even need the `distinct` due to the definition of the `in` operator. But you probably will get the same execution plan regardless.

It's ok, in my opinion, to list a `p.name` more than once if it belongs to another person. The query you wrote would have been ok if the rule started with these words:

> If a person's name ...

instead of these words:

> If a person ...

Which reminds me of something [C. J. Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date) did in class one day. He put a foil on his projector that projected an image of a smoking pipe on the wall. He then asked: what is this?

- A pipe, one guy said (probably me).
- An image of a pipe another guy said.
- Finally, someone said an image of a pipe projected on a wall.

Since it was a database class and not a physics class, nobody dared to be a smart-a**.

Comment: I'd be a little careful on using `in`, as it sometimes has performance implications.  Probably not too horrible with 1800 records, but something to be aware of for larger scale SQL transactions.  For larger numbers of records, I've found `exists` works a little bit better.

Comment: @user2366842 There is nothing wrong with `in` if you get a good execution plan, which demands that you test your code's performance as well as accuracy. We should all be testing our code's performance with acceptable data.

Comment: Ah okay, so there were people with the same name (but different person_id) that starred in movies in 2004, I understand now why it wasn't working. Thanks!